# RecyclerView Displays a Single Item When a user logs in

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The recyclerView shows a single item when an authenticated user logs in. The authenticated user has to see different photos i.e if they have uploaded different photos.

The **MainActivity** gets data from firestore and is stored in an array list which is passed to the other arraylist in the **adapter**.

**Below is the MainActivity Code Sample that gets data from firestore and stores in arrayList**

```
fStore.collection("images").whereEqualTo("userId", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
               // DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                Item item = new Item();
                itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){


                    item.setItemName(document.getData().get("name").toString());


                    item.setItemPrice(document.getData().get("price").toString());
                    item.setItemImage(document.getData().get("image").toString());
                    item.setItemDescription(document.getData().get("description").toString());
                    itemList.add(item);
                    System.out.println("This are my items:"+ itemList.get(0).getItemName());


                }
                shoeAdapter = new ShoeAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(shoeAdapter);
                shoeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
```

**The Adapter Code Sample below**

```
package com.bac.shoesrecyclerview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class ShoeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private Context context;
        private List<Item> mItems;


    public ShoeAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
            this.mItems = items;
            this.context = context;
        }

    public void removeItem(int position){
        mItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreItem(Item shoes, int position){
        mItems.add(position, shoes);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    @NonNull
        @Override
        public ShoeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Inflate the custom layout
            View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

            // Return a new holder instance
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
            return viewHolder;

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ShoeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
             Item upload = mItems.get(position);
            Glide.with(context).load(upload.getItemImage()).into(holder.imageView);
            System.out.println("ITEM ARRAY:"+ upload);

            holder.nameTextView.setText(upload.getItemName());
            holder.nameTextView2.setText(upload.getItemDescription());
            holder.textViewStock.setText(upload.getItemPrice());
            

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItems.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            public TextView nameTextView;
            public TextView nameTextView2;
            public TextView textViewStock;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public RelativeLayout displayLayout;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
              nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
               nameTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
              imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
              textViewStock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStock);
              displayLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDisplay);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Item items  = mItems.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,display_shoes.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",items.getItemName());
                intent.putExtra("description",items.getItemDescription());
                intent.putExtra("image",items.getItemImage());
                intent.putExtra("price",items.getItemPrice());


                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        }
    }
```

I debugged the above adapter by  printing what upload variable has`Item upload = mItems.get(position); System.out.println("ITEM ARRAY:"+ upload);`.

**Output From the Console**
[image]

Even though it does not hold any readable and understandable values it is showing repetition am suspecting that might be the root cause.

**The Layout of the Item activity That gets Inflated**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="244dp"
        android:background="#D81B60">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-100dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/delete_icon"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutDisplay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundshape"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:textColor="#555353"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textViewStock"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"

                android:textColor="#D81B60"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

**The Structure Of The RecyclerView**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="83dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/logOutBtn"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundcheck"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/logOutBtn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logOutBtn"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/activeperson" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LoggedIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="LoggedIn :"
            android:textColor="#F6F2F2"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_pink"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_box_24" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't add duplicate questions. You already got two answers to the previous question. If you have a question regarding those solutions, please add them there, don't post a new question.

Comment: I really dont think they are similar this one involves the recyclerview and the adapter